# Unable to run Rmpi and spawn slaves

Tags: r, mpi, mpich, ms-mpi

I'm really naive and know almost nothing about MPI. I'm trying to do some analyses in R that require Rmpi package. But I'm stuck with this problem:

```
Version of R 3.2.5 (x64) on Windows 10
```

I installed MPICH2

Added proper addresses on PATH environment variables

Successfully set smpd and mpiexec registration

```
Installed Rmpi using Rgui
```

If I call Rmpi using normal Rterm it is loaded. But when I try

`mpi.spawn.Rslaves()`, it returns :

> Error in mpi.spawn.Rslaves() : Spawning is not implemented. Please use mpiexec with Rprofile.*

so I run on prompt :

```
mpiexec  -n 2 "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.5\bin\x64\Rterm.exe" --no-save –q
```

So far so good.

I can load any package without problems but when it comes to call Rmpi library I get this error message:

> Aborting: mpi appplication on DESKTOP-0UI5TAT is unable to connect to the smpd manager on (null):57362 error 1722
>
> job aborted: 
>   [ranks] message 
>   [0] fatal error 
>   Fatal error in MPI_Init: Other MPI error, error stack: 
>   MPI_Init(argc_p=0x0018FA44, argv_p=0x0018FA48) failed 
>   The RPC server is unavailable.  (errno 1722)*

Even using the more recent MS-MPI software, when I call Rmpi it simply starts a new line without any prompt > and so it remains

I deep searched on the whole internet and tried several options but it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a shortcut that Rstudio is lunched by mpiexec ,otherwise the Rstudio doesn't know Mpi
follow instruction here
http://www.stats.uwo.ca/faculty/yu/Rmpi/